# Holomorphic $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}_-$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}_-$ be holomorphic. Show that $f$ is constant.

My attempt so far: By the riemann mapping theorem, $\mathbb{C}_-$ is biholomorphic equivalent to the open unit disk $\mathbb{E}$, hence $f$ can't be biholomorphic which is equivalent to $f: \mathbb{C} \to f(\mathbb{C})$ not being injective. So there are $z_1 \neq z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$. Here's where I'm stuck. Is my idea even correct or is there an easier way to prove this?

Comment: what is $\Bbb{C}_{-}$?

Comment: Sorry, we defined it as $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$

Comment: Pick a biholomorphic mapping $g:\mathbb{C}_{-}\rightarrow \mathbb{E}$. Then $g\circ f$ is entire and bounded, hence constant by Liouville's theorem. But then $f=g^{-1}\circ g\circ f$ is constant too.

Comment: You don't really need Riemann mapping theorem to show that $\mathbb C_-$ is biholomorphic to the open unit disc.

Comment: or if you want to completely beat this problem with a hammer, then by Picard's theorem (a significant sharpening of Louiville's theorem), an entire function is either constant or omits at most one complex value. Since your $f$ omits more than one value (it omits infinitely many), it follows $f$ is constant. (Just to be clear: I'm not suggesting you resort to Picard's theorem when simpler options are available. This comment is merely meant as an FYI, for you to be aware of the nice theorems available in complex analysis.)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yeah, a real classic :) I was fighting with myself, but did not want to nuke the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f$ has no zeroes, we may write $f(z) = e^{g(z)}$ for some holomorphic $g$. Since $f(z) \not \in \mathbb{R}_{\le 0}$, we see that $g(z) \not \in \{a+(2k+1)\pi i : a \in \mathbb{R}, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. This clearly implies that the imaginary part of $g$ is bounded (since $g$ is continuous). Therefore $h(z) := e^{ig(z)}$ is a holomorphic function that is bounded and thus is constant. So $g$ is constant, and thus $f$ is constant.

Comment: Don't you need another step? The first step seems only to imply that the imaginary part of $g$ is bounded and not directly that $g$ is bounded.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven yep, thanks! now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

On $\Bbb C_-$, you can define a holomorphic square root: if $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$, let $\sqrt z=\sqrt\rho e^{i\theta/2}$. Then $\operatorname{Re}\left(\sqrt z\right)>0$. So, if you define $g(z)=e^{-\sqrt{f(z)}}$, the $g$ is bounded, since$$\bigl|g(z)\bigr|=\left|e^{-\sqrt{f(z)}}\right|=e^{-\operatorname{Re}\left(\sqrt{f(z)}\right)}<1.$$So, by Liouville's theorem, $g$ is constant. It is easy to deduce from this and from the continuity of $f$ that $f$ is constant too.